# Code causes indentation which I like to prevent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttendeeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AttendeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 35px;">
            <a id="removeOtherAttend" href="javascript:void(0)" data-type="1" class="remove_button" style="color:#aaa;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>&nbsp; remove</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is happening is that when I view the field, it is indented. How do I prevent this indentation. All my other elements are not indented such as:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group ">
            @Html.Label("Member Attendees", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required", @multiple = "multiple" })
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Members, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Mem, new { @class = "form-control", @multiple = "multiple" }) 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a col in a col will not produce a good result, wrap cols in rows

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AttendeeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label required" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AttendeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3" style="margin-top: 35px;">
            <a id="removeOtherAttend" href="javascript:void(0)" data-type="1" class="remove_button" style="color:#aaa;"><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i>&nbsp; remove</a>
        </div>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```